# Fractional Laplacian extension problem and uniqueness question

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

I am studying the article "[An Extension Problem Related to the Fractional Laplacian](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608640)" by L. Caffarelli and L. Silvestre. Consider the following problem:
$$ \Delta_xu+\frac{a}{y}u_y+u_{yy}=0, $$
$$ u(x,0)=f(x),$$
with $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $a\in(-1,1)$. If the pointwise solution exists, is it unique? I have no idea, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, if we require $u$ to be, say, bounded. Otherwise — no. For example, both $u(x,y) = 0$ and $u(x,y) = y^{1-a}$ solve the problem with $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: How i can prove the uniqueness of the solution in the case of $u$ bounded? Can you give me the details please?

Comment: If $\|u(\cdot, y)\|_2$ is assumed to be a bounded function of $y$, then the easiest way to proceed is via Fourier transform: the PDE is then reduced to a relatively simple ODE. If I remember correctly, this is discussed already in the Caffarelli–Silvestre paper; a discussion is also given in my paper with Mucha [*Extension technique for complete Bernstein functions of the Laplace operator*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00028-018-0444-4) for more general PDEs of that form. For functions which are merely bounded, the argument is more involved, I think. If you like, I can search for references.

Comment: If $u \in C^2$ and vanishes for $y=0$ and at $\infty$, then $u=0$, by the strong maximum principle (if not it should have an interior maximum or minimum point). If $u$ is just bounded (still vanishing for $y=0$), apply this argument to $u-\epsilon y^{1-a}$ to get $u \le 0$ and then to $-u$.

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune if i remember correctly the strong maximum principle for elliptic pde work in bounded open set, but $\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\infty)$ is not bounded.

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki yes, can you give me some references please ?

Comment: @inoc The strong maximum principle holds in any open connected set, once the function has a maximum (one shows a contradiction at the maximum point). For that I assumed first that $u$ tends to 0 at infinity; in the second case I should also subtract a barrier in the $x$ direction, to get a contradiction.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune I'm not understanding much, can you give the details please?

Comment: Let us consider the simpler case where $u$ tends to 0 at infinity. If it is positive somewhere then it has a maximum in an interior point (not on the boundary where it vanishes). Then the strong maximum principle says that $u$ is a constant, hence $u=0$.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune. Great! Can you give a me reference where i can find the strong maximum princple for arbitrary connected open set please ?

Comment: Actually the usual proof of the strong maximum principle applies, since the boundedness is only used to ensure the existence of a maximum point, which follows if $u$ vanishes at infinity. However, the proof I indicated does not cover the case where $u$ is merely bounded (even for the Laplacian). I could give a semigroup proof but maybe @Mateusz Kwaśnicki has a simpler argument.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: What I had in mind is more potential-theoretic: Any *positive* solution $u$ is given by a Poisson integral plus $c y^{1-a}$ (for the Laplacian this is classical, in the general case I think it follows from the general theory of Martin boundary, and I bet there is a simpler proof availabel). This can be used to prove that every solution $u$ which is bounded by $c(1 + y^{1-a})$ has a similar representation, and this, in turn, implies the desired uniqueness result. Unfortunately, I have not enough time now to look for references, sorry.